# SSH: A to B works, B to A does not

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have two machines A and B within the organization network. I have `openssh-server` installed and `ssh` running on both the machines. Both the machines have Ubuntu 16.04.

I am able to ssh from A to B without any password. I tried setting up password-less ssh on B as well. `ssh-copy-id` does not work.

Also, ssh B to A does not work and results in timeout always. The **/etc/ssh/ssh_config** is exactly same on both the machines. Also, I am able to ssh from B to C where C is in the same network as A and B. Any pointers?

```
ssh -v user@10.x.x.2
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.x.x.2 [10.x.x.2] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.x.x.2 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.x.x.2 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Try ssh from C to A and confirm it works from C.
In A, check the output of:
```sudo service ssh status```
To start ssh service:
```sudo service ssh restart```

Comment: SSH service config is in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is the SSH client config. Is there a firewall running on A, blocking incoming traffic?

Comment: @Lambert: Thanks for your suggestion. Ideally, all machines have similar policies attached. How can I check if incoming traffic is blocked on machine A? I found a difference between sshd_config of A and B. In machine A, `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password`, while in machine B `PermitRootLogin yes`.

Comment: `sudo ufw service stop`, `sudo ufw service start` and `sudo ufw allow openssh`. This worked for me. Any explanation on this is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hosts are on the same network the most probable causes are:

- SSH service not started
- Traffic is blocked on the SSH server

According to the comments the traffic was blocked by A, disallowing access from both B and C